# How do I do client side routing in Nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js13

The problem I want to solve is that when an item in a list is clicked, the user goes to a “details” page for that item. The list is dynamic and fetched based on a user search.

I am new to next, so the approach I took was to use `<Link>` with a dynamic path using the item's id. Then create a component in `/app/page/[id].tsx`

Based on documentation, this is client-side routing, correct? I was rejected from a take-home assignment because of this and want to understand what was incorrect with my approach so I can learn!